# Interpreting R glm gamma output with interacting categorical predictors

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, categorical-data, interaction, gamma-distribution

I have a set of different gamma regressions that I ranked with AIC (with help from kind folks on CV) that show the effects of year (2019 and 2021) on "value" (an area), but I am struggling to interpret the predictors for each model. I know this has been asked and answered elsewhere, but I think I need it explained without jargon so I can really understand what's happening. Working from [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/630607/interpreting-and-transforming-glm-output-parameters-with-a-gamma-log-link), and with the simple model yearX2021 predictor below, I got exp(-0.069105) = 0.9332287. Should I interpret this as "the value in 2021 decreases an average of 1 - 0.9332287 % from whatever it was in 2019" ? I guess I'm just not sure how to interpret the "for every one unit of increase in the predictor" part of the interpretation if my predictors are categorical rather than continuous? Here is the simple model:

```
Call:
glm(formula = value ~ year, family = Gamma(link = "log"), data = SEAB_pivot)

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.276445   0.002749  100.58   <2e-16 ***
yearX2021   -0.069105   0.003887  -17.78   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Gamma family taken to be 0.2719744)

    Null deviance: 22016  on 71999  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 21930  on 71998  degrees of freedom
AIC: 135286

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5

> exp(-0.069105)
[1] 0.9332287
> 1-0.9332287
[1] 0.0667713
```

I am also struggling with how to interpret the more complicated interaction model. Here is an example with the interaction between age class (ADULT, HY, JU) and tissue type (claws, feathers). First, am I assuming that the intercept is ageADULT:tissueclaws, and the next two predictors (ageHY and ageJU) are also implied tissueclaws? Second, if I were to take exp(ageHY:tissuefeathers 1.057399) = 2.878873, "for every unit of increase in age or tissue, value increases by 187.89%" feels... very wrong. Which predictors am I comparing ageHY:tissuefeathers to in this calculation?

```
Call:
glm(formula = value ~ age * tissue, family = Gamma(link = "log"), 
    data = SEAB_pivot)

Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)           0.248006   0.002545   97.43   <2e-16 ***
ageHY                -1.287488   0.004409 -292.03   <2e-16 ***
ageJU                -0.345954   0.004409  -78.47   <2e-16 ***
tissuefeathers        0.365432   0.003600  101.52   <2e-16 ***
ageHY:tissuefeathers  1.057399   0.006235  169.59   <2e-16 ***
ageJU:tissuefeathers -0.075761   0.006235  -12.15   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Gamma family taken to be 0.1166247)

    Null deviance: 22016.1  on 71999  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  7987.2  on 71994  degrees of freedom
AIC: 60259

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

> exp(1.057399)
[1] 2.878873
```